# Can you override the send method?

Tags: contract-development

So, I understand all contracts inherit from address. Can you override the send method present in the address type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't override build in types in solidity. They are not contracts and you can override only contracts. An address is an EVM type and send is a wrapper around the CALL Opcode.

http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/contracts.html?highlight=inheritance#arguments-for-base-constructors

Comment: Currently there is no "send" opcode: `send()` uses the `CALL` opcode.